# The error message is: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

The error displays a null value for the email parameter.

```
  class RegisterEmailPage extends HookWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final formState = useState(GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>());

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {

          bool? validated = formState.value.currentState?.validate();

          if (validated == true) {
            print('Now I\'m here &&&&& formState.value.currentState?.value is: '+formState.value.currentState?.value['email'] );
            String email = formState.value.currentState?.value['email'];
            print('email is : ....' + formState.value.currentState?.value['email']);
            Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false)
                .registerCheckEmail(context, email: email, onSuccess: (res) {});
          } else {
          }
        },
```

[image]

Even though I set a few prints for get Log, I did not get any log in order to check the value of this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null from response formState.value.currentState?.value['email']. Please check the value you are getting from above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String email = formState.value.currentState?.value['email']??"Email Not Found";
```

Whenever you get null email it will take "No Email Found" value. So you do not get Null Value error.

Answer (score 0):

Since flutter2, `null` safety which has been mandatory and we have to handle `null`s when we are not sure if the response is non-null.
And there is always a possibility that

```
formState.value.currentState
```

can be `null`.

Hence you have two ways to handle this,

- you can either change your variable type to

  String? email = formState.value.currentState?.value['email'];
- or with the existing variable type you can use,

  email = formState.value.currentState?.value['email'] ?? "";

This should help.